# Creating a unique page for every user using PHP and MYSQL

Tags: php, mysql

I've started a To-do App. I've created a login and registration from and made the to-do application, but I need to have a unique to-do list for every user, right now all users get the same to-do list. I've created a database with two tables one for the to-do items(called 'todos') and one for the users. Is there any way I can link these two tables together so that each user has their own to-do items?

Here is my index.php code(registration)

```
    <?php
    // Include config file
    require 'config.php';

    // Define variables and initialize with empty values
    $username = $password = $confirm_password = "";
    $username_err = $password_err = $confirm_password_err = "";

    // Processing form data when form is submitted
    if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST"){

      // Validate username
       if(empty(trim($_POST["username"]))){
            $username_err = "Please enter a username.";
        } else{
            // Prepare a select statement
            $sql = "SELECT id FROM users WHERE username = ?";
    
            if($stmt = mysqli_prepare($link, $sql)){
                // Bind variables to the prepared statement as parameters
                mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "s", $param_username);
        
                // Set parameters
                $param_username = trim($_POST["username"]);
        
                // Attempt to execute the prepared statement
                if(mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt)){
                    /* store result */
                    mysqli_stmt_store_result($stmt);
            
                    if(mysqli_stmt_num_rows($stmt) == 1){
                        $username_err = "This username is already taken.";
                    } else{
                        $username = trim($_POST["username"]);
                    }
                } else{
                    echo "Oops! Something went wrong. Please try again later.";
                }

                // Close statement
                mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);
            }
        }

        // Validate password
        if(empty(trim($_POST["password"]))){
            $password_err = "Please enter a password.";     
        } elseif(strlen(trim($_POST["password"])) < 6){
            $password_err = "Password must have atleast 6 characters.";
        } else{
            $password = trim($_POST["password"]);
        }

        // Validate confirm password
        if(empty(trim($_POST["confirm_password"]))){
            $confirm_password_err = "Please confirm password.";     
        } else{
           $confirm_password = trim($_POST["confirm_password"]);
            if(empty($password_err) && ($password != $confirm_password)){
                $confirm_password_err = "Password did not match.";
            }
        }

// Check input errors before inserting in database
if(empty($username_err) && empty($password_err) && empty($confirm_password_err)){
    
    // Prepare an insert statement
    $sql = "INSERT INTO users (username, password) VALUES (?, ?)";
     
    if($stmt = mysqli_prepare($link, $sql)){
        // Bind variables to the prepared statement as parameters
        mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "ss", $param_username, $param_password);
        
        // Set parameters
        $param_username = $username;
        $param_password = password_hash($password, PASSWORD_DEFAULT); // Creates a password hash
        
        // Attempt to execute the prepared statement
        if(mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt)){
            // Redirect to login page
            header("location: login.php");
        } else{
            echo "Something went wrong. Please try again later.";
        }

        // Close statement
        mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);
    }
}

// Close connection
mysqli_close($link);
    }
    ?>

    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
       <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Sign Up</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.css">
        <style type="text/css">
            body{ font: 14px sans-serif; }
            .wrapper{ width: 350px; padding: 20px; }
       </style>
   </head>
   <body>
        <div class="wrapper">
            <h2>Sign Up</h2>
            <p>Please fill this form to create an account.</p>
            <form action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]); ?>" method="post">
                <div class="form-group <?php echo (!empty($username_err)) ? 'has-error' : ''; ?>">
                    <label>Username</label>
                    <input type="text" name="username" class="form-control" value="<?php echo $username; ?>">
                    <span class="help-block"><?php echo $username_err; ?></span>
                </div>    
                <div class="form-group <?php echo (!empty($password_err)) ? 'has-error' : ''; ?>">
            <label>Password</label>
            <input type="password" name="password" class="form-control" value="<?php echo $password; ?>">
            <span class="help-block"><?php echo $password_err; ?></span>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group <?php echo (!empty($confirm_password_err)) ? 'has-error' : ''; ?>">
            <label>Confirm Password</label>
            <input type="password" name="confirm_password" class="form-control" value="<?php echo $confirm_password; ?>">
            <span class="help-block"><?php echo $confirm_password_err; ?></span>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Submit">
            <input type="reset" class="btn btn-default" value="Reset">
        </div>
        <p>Already have an account? <a href="login.php">Login here</a>.</p>
    </form>
</div>    
   </body>
   </html>
```

This is my login.php code(login)

```
    <?php
    // Initialize the session
    session_start();

     // Check if the user is already logged in, if yes then redirect him to welcome page
    if(isset($_POST['loggedin']) && $_SESSION["loggedin"] === true){
        header("location: login.php");
        exit;
    }

    // Include config file
    require 'config.php';

    // Define variables and initialize with empty values
    $username = $password = "";
    $username_err = $password_err = "";

    // Processing form data when form is submitted
    if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST"){

        // Check if username is empty
        if(empty(trim($_POST["username"]))){
            $username_err = "Please enter username.";
        } else{
            $username = trim($_POST["username"]);
        }

        // Check if password is empty
        if(empty(trim($_POST["password"]))){
            $password_err = "Please enter your password.";
        } else{
            $password = trim($_POST["password"]);
        }

        // Validate credentials
        if(empty($username_err) && empty($password_err)){
           // Prepare a select statement
           $sql = "SELECT id, username, password FROM users WHERE username = ?";
    
           if($stmt = mysqli_prepare($link, $sql)){
                // Bind variables to the prepared statement as parameters
                mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "s", $param_username);
        
                // Set parameters
                $param_username = $username;
        
               // Attempt to execute the prepared statement
                if(mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt)){
                    // Store result
                    mysqli_stmt_store_result($stmt);
            
                    // Check if username exists, if yes then verify password
                    if(mysqli_stmt_num_rows($stmt) == 1){                    
                       // Bind result variables
                        mysqli_stmt_bind_result($stmt, $id, $username, $hashed_password);
                        if(mysqli_stmt_fetch($stmt)){
                           if(password_verify($password, $hashed_password)){
                                // Password is correct, so start a new session
                                session_start();
                        
                                // Store data in session variables
                               $_SESSION["loggedin"] = true;
                                $_SESSION["id"] = $id;
                                $_SESSION["username"] = $username;                            
                        
                                // Redirect user to welcome page
                                header("location: todomain.php");
                            } else{
                                // Display an error message if password is not valid
                                $password_err = "The password you entered was not valid.";
                            }
                }
            } else{
                // Display an error message if username doesn't exist
                $username_err = "No account found with that username.";
            }
        } else{
            echo "Oops! Something went wrong. Please try again later.";
        }

        // Close statement
        mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);
    }
}

// Close connection
mysqli_close($link);
    }
    ?>

    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
   <head>
       <meta charset="UTF-8">
       <title>Login</title>
       <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.css">
       <style type="text/css">
    body{ font: 14px sans-serif; }
    .wrapper{ width: 350px; padding: 20px; }
       </style>
   </head>
   <body>
        <div class="wrapper">
           <h2>Login</h2>
           <p>Please fill in your credentials to login.</p>
            <form action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]); ?>" method="post">
               <div class="form-group <?php echo (!empty($username_err)) ? 'has-error' : ''; ?>">
                   <label>Username</label>
                   <input type="text" name="username" class="form-control" value="<?php echo $username; ?>">
                    <span class="help-block"><?php echo $username_err; ?></span>
                </div>    
                <div class="form-group <?php echo (!empty($password_err)) ? 'has-error' : ''; ?>">
                    <label>Password</label>
                    <input type="password" name="password" class="form-control">
                    <span class="help-block"><?php echo $password_err; ?></span>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Login">
        </div>
        <p>Don't have an account? <a href="register.php">Sign up now</a>.</p>
    </form>
</div>    
  </body>
   </html>
```

This is my todomain.php code(this is the page that I'm redirected to when I successfully login, the main page)

```
    <?php 
    require 'db_conn.php';


   ?>
   <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
     <meta charset= "UTF-8">
     <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
     <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge"> 
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap-grid.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">


     <title>TODO App</title>
      <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/d72928d9b9.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
      </head>
     <body>
         <div class="container m-5 p-2 rounded mx-auto bg-light shadow">
         <!-- App title section -->
         <div class="row m-1 p-4">
            <div class="col">
                <div class="p-1 h1 text-primary text-center mx-auto display-inline-block">
                    <i class="fa fa-check bg-primary text-white rounded p-2"></i>
                     <u>My Todo-s</u>
               </div>
             </div>
         </div>
         <!-- Create todo section -->
        <form action="app/add.php" method="POST" autocomplete="off">
         <div class="row m-1 p-3">
             <div class="col col-11 mx-auto">
        
                 <div class="row bg-white rounded shadow-sm p-2 add-todo-wrapper align-items-center justify-content-center">
            
                    <div class="col">
                         <input class="form-control form-control-lg border-0 add-todo-input bg-transparent rounded" type="text" name="title" placeholder="Add new ..">
                     </div>
                     <div class="col-auto m-0 px-2 d-flex align-items-center">
                <label class="text-secondary my-2 p-0 px-1 view-opt-label due-date-label d-none">Due date not set</label>
                <i class="fa fa-calendar my-2 px-1 text-primary btn due-date-button" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" title="Set a Due date"></i>
                <i class="fa fa-calendar-times-o my-2 px-1 text-danger btn clear-due-date-button d-none" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" title="Clear Due date"></i>
            </div>
            
            <div class="col-auto px-0 mx-0 mr-2">
                
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Add</button>
                
                
            </div>
         
        </div>

        
    </div>
</div>
</form>
            <?php
                $todos=$conn->query("SELECT * FROM  todos ORDER BY id ASC");
              ?>

       <div class="row mx-1 px-5 pb-3 w-80">
            <div class="col mx-auto">

               <?php
               while($todo=$todos->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){ ?>
                <!-- Todo Item 1 -->

        
        <div class="row px-3 align-items-center todo-item rounded">

            <?php if($todo['checked']){ ?>
            
            <input type="checkbox" class="check-box" data-todo-id="<?php echo $todo['id'];?>" checked />
        <h2 class="checked"><?php echo $todo['title'] ?> </h2>
        <div class="col-auto m-1 p-0 todo-actions">
                <div class="row d-flex align-items-center justify-content-end">
          
        </div>
      </div>
    
         

                  
        <?php } else{ ?>
            <input type="checkbox" class="check-box" data-todo-id="<?php echo $todo['id'];?>"/>
             <h2><?php echo $todo['title'] ?></h2>
               
                      

        <?php } ?>

            <div class="col-auto m-1 p-0 d-flex align-items-center">


                <h2 class="m-0 p-0">
                    <i class="fa fa-square-o text-primary btn m-0 p-0 d-none" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" title="Mark as complete"></i>
                    
                </h2>
            </div>
           
            
         
            <div class="col-auto m-1 p-0 todo-actions">
                <div class="row d-flex align-items-center justify-content-end">

                    <h5 class="m-0 p-0 px-2">
                        <i class="fa fa-pencil text-info btn m-0 p-0" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" title="Edit todo"></i>
                    </h5>
                    <h5 class="m-0 p-0 px-2">
                      
                         
                    <i class="remove-to-do fa fa-trash-o text-danger btn m-0 p-0" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" title="Delete todo" id="<?php echo $todo['id']; ?>"></i>
                  </h5> 
                </div>
                <div class="row todo-created-info">
                    <div class="col-auto d-flex align-items-center pr-2">
                        <i class="fa fa-info-circle my-2 px-2 text-black-50 btn" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" title="" data-original-title="Created date"></i>
                        <label class="date-label my-2 text-black-50"><?php echo $todo['date_time'] ?></label>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    
            <?php } ?>













    </div>

      <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
       <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
        <script src="js/myjs.js" ></script>
        <script src="js/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>

        <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){

      $(".remove-to-do").click(function(e){
            const id = $(this).attr('id');
             $.post('app/remove.php', 
                  {
                      id: id
                  },
                  (data) => {
                     if(data){
                        $(this).parent().parent().parent().parent().hide(300);
                     }
                  }

            );
            
           
        });
      




        $(".check-box").click(function(e){
            const id = $(this).attr('data-todo-id');
            
            $.post('app/checking.php', 
                  {
                      id: id
                  },
                  (data) => {
                     if(data!='error'){
                        const h2= $(this).next();
                        if(data === '1'){
                            h2.removeClass('checked');
                        }else{
                            h2.addclass('checked');
                        }
                     }
                  }

            );
        });
    });
</script>


    </body>
     </html>
```

Comment: Please do **not** vandalize your posts (rolled back).

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please don't make more work for other people by vandalizing your posts. By posting on the Stack Exchange network, you've granted a non-revocable right, under the [CC BY-SA 4.0 license](//creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0/), for Stack Exchange to distribute that content (i.e. regardless of your future choices). By Stack Exchange policy, the non-vandalized version of the post is the one which is distributed. Thus, any vandalism will be reverted. If you want to know more about deleting a post please see: [How does deleting work?](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/5221)

Answer (score 2):

You'll need to add a relationship between **todo** and **user**, the best option is a FOREIGN KEY but is optional.

```
| users    | | todo    |
|----------| |---------|
| id       | | id      |
| username | | user_id |
| password | | title   |
             | checked |
```

So, you keep your user **id** when they login inside a $_SESSION and every time you list or insert things on the **todo** you use this reference:

```sql
INSERT INTO todo (user_id, title) VALUES (10, 'My Todo') -- or any other id
SELECT * FROM todo WHERE user_id = 10 -- or any other id
```

On PHP with `PDO`:

```php
$stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO todos (user_id, title) VALUES (:user_id, :title)");
$stmt->execute([':user_id' => $user_id, ':title' => $title]);
```

On PHP with `mysqli` bind parameters you can do in this way:

```php
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO todos (user_id, title) VALUES (?, ?)");
$stmt->bind_param("is", $user_id, $title);
$res = $stmt->execute();
```

Comment: Created a foreign key called user_id and tried doing what you said and now it will not let me add any items

Comment: The `foreign key` are a constraint to keep your data integrity, but if you're learning don't use if for now, get used with all your code first.